# Standalone CQ5 publish instances without cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, aem, sling

I am looking for the best solution for having multiple publish instances. I tried shared nothing and shared datastore configurations.

Is there any advantages or disadvantages of **having 2 or more publish instances without cluster setup**? In such a configuration how can I start a new publish instance? I mean **how I should replicate the data from the author when I start a new publish instance** (probably from backup), what are the best practices for this. **How to solve reverse replication issues**, so while I starting a new instance, other publish instance might get some new user generated data which must be replicated to the new publish instance too. What is your experience in this topic?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Multiple publish instances allow you to use a load balancer & increase the amount of concurrent users your site can serve.
2. Replcation of content can be done in the standard way, using CRX Package replcation or the Activation tree, once you've set up a replication agent per instance.
3. You shouldn't run into too much difficulty with content generated while the instance is being set up, as once the instance is up & running, you can just activate it in the normal way. (If you think it will be an issue, you could probably set-up the replication agent first, so that new content is queued while the instance is being set-up, though I couldn't see why you would need to do this).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you tell me please whether there is any advantage or disadvantage having standalone multiple publish instances without any cluster configuration or having multiple instances with master-slave setup.

Comment: Adobe's recommendation is that publish instances don't particularly need to be clustered, replication & then sitting a load balancer in front should be fine.

Comment: Thanks! I've got the same answer from other sources, but I have never got the full answer. **Why** does Adobe recommend this, and where can I find this recommendation. Sorry for that, but as a developer I'm always looking for answers. :)

Comment: Sorry, don't have a reference, I was given the recommendation through word-of-mouth :) I presume though because there's a performance impact of syncing repositories via clustering, this can be alleviated on the customer-facing publish instances by using replication (/reverse replication) instead. With clustered authoring instances, you want your authors to be able to use any instance & replication in a many-to-many fashion would be much harder to maintain.